# XCode 4.6.2 issue after update. (error: PCH file built from a different branch )

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

My project works fine in previous versions of Xcode. Now I've updated to Xcode 4.6.2, and I'm getting this error:

> PCH file built from a different branch ((clang-425.0.27)) than the compiler ((clang-425.0.28))

Is this a bug in Xcode? How do I fix it?

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko is correct, doing a Clean will fix the problem.

Comment: i have cleaned project still not working.

Comment: you have to clean the build folder (hold alt-key)

Comment: thank you guys for your co-operation done.

Answer (score 23):

Specially if you build from command line or you have a build script, cleaning xcode target is not enough. You have to delete this folder.

The precompiled header location can be found in the

```
Target -> build settings => "Build locations" -> Precompiled headers cached path
```

Open `Terminal`, `cd` to the folder path and delete the folder with,

```
#rm -fr SharedPrecompiledHeaders
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Done i have `closed xcode project then started again` and `CMD+SHIFT+K`. This logic is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried Clean Build Folder 10 times, never fixed it. Closed Xcode, started again, Cleaned Build Folder, then the build worked properly. Thanks!